# Embedding pixlr in a website - http post is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, flash, pixlr

I am working on integrating pixlr ([www.pixlr.com](http://www.pixlr.com)) with my website. I am using the request type POST by setting the method property to POST and I am sending image from my web application by converting it to Base64 encoded data.But pixlr server is giving "414 Request-URI Too Large" error as it is accepting my request as GET request.Why is it sending GET request even after I changed the method to POST?

Answer (score 0):

I instead of embeding you can just put a iframe Code,For Pixlr editor iframe on your website
    
POixlr has started showing adsenbse ad also hence the iframe will also show advertisment.You can go to www.toolpic.com it same like pixlr with animation and shrotcut effect which pixlr do not have.for iframe of toolpic 
     
The code thing is toolpic do not have any advertsiment on that page. and seems to have lots of extra function which pixlr do not have. 
Hope iut Helps 
Thanks